# pe:inputNumber rounding 4 digits

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I have a problem with primefaces extensions about rounding numbers

From database the value is coming as 1.24569833 but on the screen the number is printed as 1.240000. But I want that the number is printed as 1.245700. Shortly I want to round the number coming from database 4 digits.

```
 <pe:inputNumber
                disabled="#{expenseBean.renderMode.currencyRateInputDisabled()}"
                decimalPlaces="6" 
                rendered="#{!expenseBean.renderMode.kdvPanelRendered()}"
                id="defaultCurrencyRate"
                value="#{expenseBean.expense.selectedExpenseSpending.spendingCurrencyRate}">
```

I heard roundMethod attribute of inputNumber but that did not fix my problem. Can you help me?

**Edit:** InputNumber has been promoted to core PrimeFaces and is no longer in Extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake. The problem is version of the primefaces extensions. The old version is 0.4 , after updating it to 0.5.1 and also primefaces 3.3.1 or higher roundMethod is working.